# How to disable foreign keys while INSERT in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I've got two MySQL databases: one with data, the other is empty.
They have similar tables, and I want to copy data from db1.table to db2.table.
The table contains parent_id FOREIGN KEY.

Here's my query:

```
INSERT INTO db2.table (id, name, parent_id) (SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM db1.table);
```

When I run it, it fails with foreign key constraint violation (parent_id).

But when I run this before query

```
ALTER TABLE db2.table DROP FOREIGN KEY
```

and this after query

```
ALTER TABLE db2.table ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY
```

then all works fine. But I don't like this solution with 3 queries. I want to INSERT using one query.

So it looks like when INSERT runs, it processes rows in wrong order, so for some row `parent_id` isn't inserted yet, so violation fails.

How to do such INSERT?

Comment: thank you! Why didn't I found it myself? I've searched, honestly!

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you found it useful!